# Console Write Wrapper in Windows

Tags: c++, c, operating-system

When we wrote a simple program like the following one in C++:

```
int main(){
    cout << "Something" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In Linux finally, write system call will be called in order to output the "Something" character sequence in the console. I wonder to know, what system call will be called in Windows (Windows 7 later) and how can I found out that information?

In Linux, we have a program like strace to find this information but for Windows, I didn't find out anything special. Can someone explain this process in Windows? I want to trace system calls that triggered by Windows.

In other word, I want to know what will happen when we use cout in cpp and how this operator can to write something in the standard output.

Comment: Write system call will be called to output some characters into standard output and if you have some sort of terminal emulator on the other end of the pipe it may display something. On windows things are mostly the same.

Comment: Your example is incorrect. C++ `std::cout` is much more than just one system call. The better example would be with the `printf` function.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov So, I would like to know what will happen when we call std::cout.

Comment: Please clarify the question.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov I did it.

Comment: You mix several non-related things into one. What are you trying to understand, the difference between Linux/Windows? The difference between C/C++, printf/std::cout?

Comment: Any specific Windows version or all (= very long answer)? Linux is also not the only *nix OS out there. Side note: "_As you know, when we wrote a simple program like the following one in C++_" - no, never.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov I want to know the internal working of cout/printf in windows and how finally printf/cout can to output a character sequence in the standard output. I am familiar with the stuff in Linux but I didn't have enough information in windows.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I fix my question. Windows 7 or later.

Comment: std::cout in C++ is not a full analogy of printf in C/C++. So please clarify: do you need to know the difference between cout/printf of you need to know what is below the printf.

Comment: Use a debugger and trace it through the `std::cout` function til you get to the Windows system calls. It's complex. the std io code is system/compiler specific.

Comment: There's also NtTrace for if you want to look at how programs interact with the OS

Comment: @cph So, you're in search for a Windows 7+ specific implementation? At what level? It's a bit uncear.what you're asking about. Can you provide a [mcve] to demonstrate?

Comment: The source code for VisualStudio's standard library ships with VisualStudio.  You could read it and figure out exactly what `std::cout` does.  From my quick look, it's using a `FILE*` underneath, so at some point I assume it uses the [`WriteFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile) win32 API to actually write characters to the console.

Comment: @MilesBudnek FILE* and WriteFile are from different universes

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov Sure, but one of those universes is built on the other.  The MSVCRT is just a standardized interface around the Win32 API.  The C++ `filebuf` ends up calling the C `fwrite`, which ends up calling the POSIX-like `_write`, which in turn calls the Win32 `WriteFile`.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov Please explain this clearly if you know the internal working of cout because it is really complex and not clearly understandable. If CPP Runtime finally didn't call WriteFile or WriteConsole API to output a character sequence in the console, so what had been happened?

Comment: @cph in brief, there is one more level between the iostream level and system calls. First, streams are stateful: you can change the parameters of the stream, i.e. precision, and next call would produce different result. Second, streams are buffered. It is not guaranteed that it will output something the device in the exact moment when you output something to the stream. As the most obvious example try to identify the difference between outputing the newline literal '\n' and the object std::endl.